# How to use OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient without Vary: * HTTP header

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to use OutputCache for both server and client caching on an MVC view but setting Location to ServerAndClient forces the HTTP header `Vary: *` to be set, which largely defeats the purpose of the client caching (it tells the browser to check for freshness EVERY time the resource is used).

I want the browser to cache the file for 24hours and only make another request if I change the LastModifield parameter that I add to the querystring. This works if I have only Client as the location but I also want the server to cache the file so that it doesn't need to regenerate it when another user requests the same resource.

The resource is based on a database that will rarely get updated (possibly once or twice a month, I know when it has changed) and the resource could get hit very hard so I don't want to be generating it all the time or even handling modified-since conditionaly requests.

My OutputCache attribute is:

`[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient, Duration = 86400, VaryByParam = "LastModified")]`

I have tried extending the OutputCacheAttribute class and overriding all of the On* methods and removing the Vary http header but the Vary header doesn't seem to be added until AFTER all of these methods have been called.

Answer (score 3):

`Response.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);`

Comment: or globally https://stackoverflow.com/a/13509708/1507124