# Removing Vary:* response header from asp.net mvc 4.6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, response-headers

How do I remove the Vary:* from the response header for all my requests in the WEB APP (ASP.NET MVC)

Thanks

Comment: This appears to be for an older version but does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573501/how-to-supress-header-vary-when-using-outputcacheprofiles

Comment: Do you want to remove the Vary header so that it does not appear in the responses at all or do you only want to remove `Vary:*` so `Vary:Accept-Encoding `would be okay?

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, you can use [ResponseCacheAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.responsecacheattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.0), as explained in [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response).

Answer (score 0):

The below code might help you.

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Vary");
}
```

or in your web.config like:

```
<system.webServer> 
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders> 
            <remove name="Vary" />
        </customHeaders> 
    </httpProtocol> 
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13509708/1507124 is likely the better approach